# `thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }', lang/syn/src/idl/mod.rs:214:76`

Tags: anchor, rust

`thread 'main' panicked at 'called` Result::unwrap()`on an`Err `value: ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }', lang/syn/src/idl/mod.rs:214:76`

I'm new to anchor and using it for past two weeks. I wanted to use a helper function `eth_addr()` for a signature verification. So I implemented it in a enum, when I try to use it in the `lib.rs` it throws me the above error. I have implemented `eth_addr()` returning a const value of usize.

type.rs

```
  pub const PUB_KEY_SIZE: usize = 20;

   pub fn eth_addr(&self) -> [u8; PUB_KEY_SIZE] {
       match self {
           Self::MintSignature {
               eth_addr,
               sig_r: _,
               sig_s: _,
               sig_v: _,
               msg: _,
           } => *eth_addr,
       }
```

lib.rs

```
 if state.authority != secp256k1_instruction_data.eth_addr() {
            msg!("Error: Invalid signer for the mint signature");
            return err!(Error::InvalidSigner);
        }
```

`secp256k1_instruction_data` is the unpacked instruction data of enum `Secp256k1InstructionData` where `eth_addr()` has been implemented.

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }', lang/syn/src/idl/mod.rs:214:76
stack backtrace:
   0:        0x10466c0dc - <std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::DisplayBacktrace as core::fmt::Display>::fmt::h188b7ef1c7993e78
   1:        0x1043dfd44 - core::fmt::write::he84a3004e7af3f34
   2:        0x104647a58 - std::io::Write::write_fmt::h9370b50affaab0be
   3:        0x104670f98 - std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}::hc074f8023cce83ca
   4:        0x104671e10 - std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook::h1e59e224d558a492
   5:        0x1046719dc - std::panicking::begin_panic_handler::{{closure}}::he1a9d6ab32bfd8c6
   6:        0x104671954 - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_end_short_backtrace::he9b94791b02f48cd
   7:        0x104671920 - _rust_begin_unwind
   8:        0x1047f5950 - core::panicking::panic_fmt::h9fec86f6a9c4146e
   9:        0x1047f5b08 - core::result::unwrap_failed::h04f08301b97a771c
  10:        0x104395958 - <anchor_syn::idl::IdlType as core::str::traits::FromStr>::from_str::array_from_str::h2ff42bfe7bf35b61
  11:        0x104394dfc - <anchor_syn::idl::IdlType as core::str::traits::FromStr>::from_str::hf718c6ba731d402a
  12:        0x104357c4c - anchor_syn::idl::file::to_idl_type::h1ea386dfbceee694
  13:        0x104358094 - core::ops::function::impls::<impl core::ops::function::FnOnce<A> for &mut F>::call_once::haa47edb8ccd6241e
  14:        0x1043585bc - core::ops::function::impls::<impl core::ops::function::FnOnce<A> for &mut F>::call_once::hd89ac91d85975486
  15:        0x10439b68c - <core::iter::adapters::filter_map::FilterMap<I,F> as core::iter::traits::iterator::Iterator>::try_fold::heed2912c2746a817
  16:        0x10437afac - <core::iter::adapters::GenericShunt<I,R> as core::iter::traits::iterator::Iterator>::next::h6c24577be838490d
  17:        0x10435a23c - anchor_syn::idl::file::parse_ty_defs::h11873edcbd63c65c
  18:        0x10430d950 - anchor_syn::idl::file::parse::hfbb2577322f5f915
  19:        0x104288dc0 - anchor_cli::extract_idl::h47360cc7ebe268b6
  20:        0x104311dd8 - anchor_cli::build_cwd::h62d1ef82604fd1c5
  21:        0x1043115d4 - anchor_cli::build_all::h1cfceec859897162
  22:        0x104287048 - anchor_cli::build::h564fd188568c0bb6
  23:        0x104275a70 - anchor_cli::entry::h0256f27efce20e7b
  24:        0x1041b4f38 - anchor::main::h3ca4f6d7a3d2f4cf
  25:        0x1041b34cc - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h16950677100173d7
  26:        0x1041b34f0 - std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}::ha35d8116774c78f5
  27:        0x1041b55a0 - _main
```

Please let me know if any further info is needed.

Comment: You may need to add more information about your full state and instruction info, since `ParseIntError` makes it look like there's some invalid data passed in from the outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ParseIntError is because an InvalidDigit is passed somewhere.
In your example, this error is generated in the line:

```
pub fn eth_addr(&self) -> [u8; PUB_KEY_SIZE] {
```

Try to use a number instead a varible, something like this:

```
pub fn eth_addr(&self) -> [u8; 20] {
```

It is possible that variables are not accepted there, check it.

Comment: Yes that's exactly the issue. I found out and fixed it. Thanks for the help.